# Notification for changes to an AVAudioSession's inputAvailable property

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I'm switching things over from the C AudioSession API to the AVAudioSession API. The delegate methods for `AVAudioSessionDelegate`s are deprecated, so I'm implementing notification handlers for those notifications that an `AVAudioSession` posts. I'm handling route changes, etc. just fine. However, I previously had a property listener handling changes to input availability, but I can't seem to find a matching notification for these changes. Am I missing something?

Comment: I wonder why they deprecated the delegate? I can't see a relevant notification either, however couldn't you check the classes property instead?

Comment: I don't really want to poll the property--that's *why* we use delegates/listeners/notifications after all, right?

Comment: Yes indeed you are of course correct, it's quite strange for me that they decided to deprecate delegates and then not implement enough notifications!